# Bash - How to get the name a folder inside the current folder?

Tags: bash, shell, directory

Let's say my script is running inside a folder, and in this folder is anther folder with a name that can change each time I run the script. How can I find the name of that folder ?

**Edit** :

As an example, let's say my script is running in the folder `/testfolder`, which is known and does not change.

In `/testfolder` there is another folder : `/testfolder/randomfolder`, which is unknown and can change.

How do I find the name of `/randomfolder` ?

I hope it's clearer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: An example would be helpful for clarity.

Comment: What do you know of the name of the folder at the time you run the sript?  In other words, how would your script know what folder to look for?  Or there can be only one?

Comment: @ColinD, [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming there is exactly one subdirectory:

```
dir=$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

If you don't have GNU find, then

```
for f in *; do [[ -d "$f" ]] && { dir=$f; break; }; done
```

Answer (score 12):

```
dirs=(/testfolder/*/)
```

`dirs` will be an array containing the names of each directory that is a direct subdirectory of `/testfolder`.

If there's only one, you can access it like this:

```
echo "$dirs"
```

or

```
echo "${dirs[0]}"
```

If there is more than one and you want to iterate over them:

```
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    echo "$dir"
done
```